# Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to show that $e^x = \sin(x)$ has infinite solutions.

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I am not entirely sure about how to prove this algebraically. Although, I can clearly see that $e^x = \sin (x)$ has infinite solutions when I plot the graph. I can't seem to figure out how to methodically demonstrate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\overline{x}_n = -\frac{3\pi}{2}-2n \pi$, and $\underline{x}_n = - \frac{\pi}{2} - 2n \pi$, $n=1,...$. Clearly $\overline{x}_n < \underline{x}_n$,
$\sin \overline{x}_n =+1$, $\sin \underline{x}_n = -1$. Also, $0<e^{\overline{x}_n} <1$, and $0<e^{\underline{x}_n} <1$.

Hence $\sin \overline{x}_n > e^{\overline{x}_n}$ and $\sin \underline{x}_n < e^{\underline{x}_n}$.

The intermediate value theorem states that there exists some $t_n \in (\overline{x}_n, \underline{x}_n)$ such that $\sin \overline{t}_n = e^{\overline{t}_n}$.

The set $\{t_n\}$ is infinite.

Comment: I don't think you need negative signs in the exponent with your definition of two sequences.

Comment: @sas Thank you for finding that error after so many years!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the idea, you can make it more rigorous:

$e^x \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow - \infty$,

so for sufficiently large negatives, $e^x$ is very small.

But then looking only at sufficiently large negatives, we can find infinitely many pairs $x,y$ (you'll have to choose these pairs correctly) such that $\mathrm{sin}(x) = -1$ and $\mathrm{sin}(y) = 1$.

Then you can apply the IVT on the interval $(x,y)$.