# Proving $\cos(x+y)+\sin(xy)=x^2+y$ has infinite solutions using intermediate value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

I have to use the intermediate value theorem (IVT) to show that the equation $\cos(x+y) + \sin(xy) = x^2 + y$

1. Has infinitely many solutions in $x,y$, and
2. The set of all solutions is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

So far, I have plotted the equation ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20cos(x%2By)%20%2B%20sin(yx)%20%3D%20x%5E2%20%2B%20y)), and read similar posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235174/show-that-2x-tan-x-has-infinitely-many-solutions-using-the-intermediate-value) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520537/use-the-intermediate-value-theorem-to-show-that-ex-sinx-has-infinite-sol) but I am not sure how to proceed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

PS: One hint I got was to fix $y$ and apply the IVT repeatedly. So I fixed $y=0.5$ and plotted $f(x) = \cos(x+0.5) + \sin(0.5x) - x^2 - 0.5$ ([link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos(x%2B0.5)%20%2B%20sin(0.5x)%20-%20x%5E2%20-%200.5)). I noticed that when I fix $y$ such that $y<1$, the function intersects (or is tangent too) the $x$ axis, whereas for $y \geq 1$, it does not touch the axis. I'm not sure how to use this to prove 1 and 2 above.

Comment: For 1, it might be nicer to fix $x$ and then imagine $y$ varying from $-x^2 - 2$ to $-x^2 + 2$.

Comment: The set of solutions is closed regardless of 1. Note that we have two continuous functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ and that $\{(x,y): f(x,y) = g(x,y)\} = \{(x,y); f(x,y) - g(x,y) = 0\}= h^{-1}[\{0\}]$ where $h(x,y) = f(x,y) - g(x,y)$ is continuous too, and so the inverse image of a closed set under $h$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I understand that $\sin(xy)+ \cos(x+y)$ is bounded in $(-2,2)$. But how do I show that there are infinitely many solutions?

Comment: Thanks Henno, that makes sense